# FullCalendar: Allow event creation/selection only in given time slots i.e. within "availableForMeeting" constraint time slots

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar v5.10.0
Is there any feature in full calendar that efficiently allows event creation only in a particular time slots i.e. Only within "availableForMeeting" time slots.

As shown in below image I want to restrict users to create events only in green highlighted time slots i.e. "availableForMeeting" time slots as defined in code below.

**Expected behavior -**
According to current code it does not allow users to create events outside defined business hours i.e. should not allow to create events in grayed out time slots.
In short behavior should be similar to above business hours feature for all time slots which are outside of green highlighted "availableForMeeting" time slots.

[image]

**Code -**

```js
<div id='calendar'></div>
<div>
    Locales:
    <select id='locale-selector'></select>
</div>
<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        var initialLocaleCode = 'en';
        var localeSelectorEl = document.getElementById('locale-selector');

        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
            selectable: true,
            unselectAuto: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            editable: true,
            locale: initialLocaleCode,
            selectConstraint: "businessHours",
            eventConstraint: "businessHours",
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            events: [
                {
                    "title": "Meeting",
                    "start": "2021-10-21T13:00:00",
                    "end": "2021-10-21T13:40:00",
                    "constraint": "availableForMeeting",
                    "overlap": false,
                    "color": "#257e4a"
                },
                {
                    "groupId": "availableForMeeting",
                    "start": "2021-10-18T10:00:00",
                    "end": "2021-10-18T17:00:00",
                    "display": "background"
                },
                {
                    "groupId": "availableForMeeting",
                    "start": "2021-10-21T12:00:00",
                    "end": "2021-10-21T15:00:00",
                    "display": "background"
                }
            ],
            select: function (selectionInfo) {
                var selectionStart = moment(selectionInfo.start);
                var today = moment(); // passing moment nothing defaults to today

                if (selectionStart < today) {
                    calendar.unselect()
                }
                else {
                    var eventName = prompt('Enter Title');
                    if (eventName) {
                        var allDay = !selectionInfo.start.hasTime && !selectionInfo.end.hasTime;
                        var newEvent = new Object();
                        newEvent.title = eventName;
                        newEvent.start = selectionInfo.start;
                        newEvent.end = selectionInfo.end;
                        newEvent.allDay = false;
                        newEvent.stick = true;
                        newEvent.constraint = 'availableForMeeting';
                        calendar.addEvent(newEvent);
                    }
                }
            },
            selectOverlap: function (event) {
                return event.rendering === 'background';
            }
        });

        calendar.setOption('businessHours', 
             [
                {
                    daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    startTime: '08:00',
                    endTime: '12:00'
                },
                {
                    daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    startTime: '13:00',
                    endTime: '17:00'
                }
            ]
        );

        calendar.render();

        // build the locale selector's options
        calendar.getAvailableLocaleCodes().forEach(function (localeCode) {
            var optionEl = document.createElement('option');
            optionEl.value = localeCode;
            optionEl.selected = localeCode == initialLocaleCode;
            optionEl.innerText = localeCode;
            localeSelectorEl.appendChild(optionEl);
        });

        // when the selected option changes, dynamically change the calendar option
        localeSelectorEl.addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (this.value) {
                calendar.setOption('locale', this.value);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Look at the example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap - it appears to be exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @ADyson I did try  selectOverlap but it does opposite of what I am trying to do. its NOT allowing me to create events in availableForMeeting (green colored) time slots and allows me to create events in other time slots (White time slots). I want to create events only on green colored background events  and not everywhere else.

Comment: Since you're already using businessHours to restrict the hours available to those shown in white, wouldn't it make more sense, from a UI perspective, to use the background events to cover the areas within the businessHours which are _not_ available? It would be a lot less confusing, because to the user it's not clear what the difference between the white and grey areas is, if neither can be selected.

Comment: Yes it does makes sense. actually I had same in mind but that way I will have to calculate time slots which are not available inside business hours i.e. Available business hours - Green time slots = red background events which are not available. 
I was being lazy and was trying to find if there is any feature to do this. I guess I shoud experiment with display: 'inverse-background' feature